# When installing python libraries via cmd, I enter the command ( pip instal numpy )in cmd, it shows me an error

Tags: python, pip

When installing python libraries via cmd, I enter the command ( pip instal numpy )in cmd, it shows me an error ==> 'pip' is not recognized as a[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yIvi6.png)n internal or external command, operable program or batch file.                                          ....

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LXYxU.png)                                                                                   f